# A question about the subordinate clause of a sentence

Tags: grammar

I'm an English learner from Asia.

> But a different kind of rejuvenation is trending online, that of “run philosophy”, a coded way of talking about emigration.

In the sentence above, what does "that of run philosophy" do in the sentence? And why is it written this way? Does this sentence omit something?

Here is the link to [the article from the Economist](https://www.economist.com/china/2022/05/05/chinas-young-elite-are-considering-moving-abroad).
The sentence is in the first paragraph of the article, which can be previewed without a subscription.

Comment: where is this sentence from?

Comment: Yes please give a source for quotations used here on ELL, an author and place of publication, and if possible, a link. When you wrote the text yourself, please say so. Doing this gives proper attribution, and makes it possible to find additional context, which is often helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Here is the link, [an article from the Economist](https://www.economist.com/china/2022/05/05/chinas-young-elite-are-considering-moving-abroad) . And this sentence is in the first paragraph of the article, which can be previewed without being subscribed

Comment: Looking at [this article](https://dexter.substack.com/p/trade-war-ae7?s=r), where it says *Users of Weibo ... published more than 78,000 posts with the **run** character in March and April,”* it seems pretty obvious it's a reference to ***Chinese*** Twitterati or similar deliberately using some particular lexicographic character that doesn't explicitly mean ***running away from** [China, because of the oppressive political / economic regime]* because then their posts would be censored by the authorities. But the intended audience (other "malcontents") will understand the "coded reference".

Answer (score 1):

The pronoun "that" heads the nominal phrase "that of “run philosophy”, a coded way of talking about emigration". The entire phrase functions as an appositive, referring to "a different kind of rejuvenation". A more standard word order would be:

> But a different kind of rejuvenation, that of “run philosophy”, a coded way of talking about emigration, is trending online.

The author probably postponed the appositive because it is fairly long; doing so is quite common in English.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I still wonder whether this appositive clause, " that of 'run philosophy' "  has omit something, like the subject or the predicate. If yes, what the sentence will be like without these ellipses? Besides, in which case we ususlly do this kind of ellipses?

Comment: @DFG It's not an appositive. It's a content clause functioning as a **supplement** with the NP "a different kind of rejuvenation" as its reference (called the 'anchor'). We know it's not an appositive because it can't be substituted for the whole supplementation yielding an entailment of the original. Note that the phrase "that of" (called the 'indicator') serves to clarify the nature of its semantic relationship to the anchor.

Comment: @DFG A nominal appositive doesn't need a predicate. It is simply a nominal phrase, and nothing has been omitted. (BillJ defines "appositive" differently from how I do and has thus analyzed the sentence differently.)

Comment: Thanks for the generous help from both of you! I have unsderstanded! I had thought "that" is a conjunction here, for which I had made this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> *But a different kind of rejuvenation is trending online,* [*that of “run*
> *philosophy”*]*, a coded way of talking about emigration.*

The bracketed element is a content clause functioning as a **supplement** that has the NP "a different kind of rejuvenation" as its reference (called the 'anchor').

At first glance it may appear to be an appositive clause, but we know it's not because it can't be substituted for the whole supplementation yielding an entailment of the original.

Note that the phrase "that of" (called the 'indicator') serves to clarify the nature of its semantic relationship to the anchor.